# Что это? $a--;

Tags: php

Что это значит:

```
$a--;
```

?

Comment: Да, слишком. Символов, которые вы потратили на издевку хватило бы на развернутый ответ. Так сложно воздержаться? =) Голос против существует, в конце концов.

Comment: @knes Сложно не то слово :DDD И то что их хватило бы на развёрнутый ответ ещё подливает масла в огонь :DDDDDD

Comment: Да ладно, что вы на человека напали? Все когда-то были новичками.

Comment: @Fatahan, неа, ++$mikillskegg; ))))))  
@mikillskegg, МЫ? О_о или это вежливое обращение? На какого человека?

Comment: Спасибо, что не $mikillskegg-- )))

Comment: @knes, это типа оборот речи.

Comment: А Вам, уважаемый @nick777, я настоятельно рекомендую учить язык систематически, т.е. взять нормальный учебник и проработать его от корки до корки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Постдекремент.

`$a--;` Возвращает значение $a, а потом уменьшает $a на единицу.

```
$a = 9;
$b = $a--;//$b = 9, $a = 8
```

`--$a;` Уменьшает $a на единицу, потом возвращает это значение.

```
$a = 9;
$b = --$a;//$b = 8, $a = 8
```

Answer (score 3):

если ты знаеш другие языки хотя бы Паскаль
то это

```
 var a:integer;//например чисельная переменная
    а:=a-1;
```

Comment: Вопервых - Это вообще что?  :D

Вовторых - Причём тут Пэскаль?

Comment: а я не знаешь чисельный переменный запятая. :(

Answer (score 2):

Декремент. $a = $a - 1;

---

**UPD**

[Справка](http://doc.php5.com.ua/language.operators.increment/)

Comment: --$a это то что вы написали, $a-- работает несколько иначе

Comment: В данном контексте это не принципиально.

Comment: Контекста не указано. =)

Comment: В том то и дело что контект неуказан почему ответ не верный

Comment: Вы несогласны что это декремент? Или в том что значение будет на единицу меньше? Что постфиксный, что префиксный декременты при использовании не в выражении, а отдельно, вернут одинаковый результат?

Comment: Ага. Но вот вы написали это человеку, который первый раз видит эту конструкцию. Без уточнения, заметьте, написали. А дальше человек обнаружит кучу забавно ведущих себя скриптов, когда заменит все на `$a--`;

Comment: Для яндекса этого достаточно (прошу прощения, но лично я в свое время обучался с помощью яндекса, мануалов и любопытства). Согласен, что я немного легкомысленно дал неполный ответ новичку на довольно запутанную тему. В качестве исправления своего недостойного поведения добавил в ответ ссылку на небольшое разъяснение.

Comment: @knes "А дальше человек обнаружит кучу забавно ведущих себя скриптов" <- :DDDD

Answer (score 0):

Ну и вопрос! Ты PHP вообще что ли не знаешь? Если каждый подобный вопрос будешь оставлять здесь, то этот сайт станет пособием по PHP))) **Читай мануал!**

```
> $a-- //это декремент(школьный курс алгебры).
```

Comment: Еще один. =)
См. комментарии к посту участника @Valeriy Karchov